# NASM - Bootloader Printline

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader, bios

I have written a simple bootloader based on:  http://www.viralpatel.net/taj/tutorial/hello_world_bootloader.php

It should only display "Booting..." on the screen, but it also displays each message I defined("Booting...Remove disk and press enter for reboot..."). How can I fix it?

This is my code:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]

xor ax,ax
mov ds,ax

mov si, msg_boot
call printline

loop:
jmp loop

reboot:
mov si, msg_remove_disk
call printline
call .inputcheck
ret
.inputcheck:
call input
cmp al, 13
je .end
jmp .inputcheck
.end:
call reset
ret

reset:
db 0Eah
dw 0000h
dw 0FFFFh
ret

exit:
ret

print:
mov al, [si]
inc si
or al, al
jz exit
mov ah, 0x0E
int 0x10
jmp print

printline:
call print
mov al, endofline
call print
ret

input:
mov ah, 0
int 16h
ret

msg_boot db 'Booting...', 0
msg_remove_disk db 'Remove disk and press enter for reboot...', 0

endofline db 13, 10, 0

TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
DW 0xAA55
```

Comment: In this code it looks like you're purposefully showing both messages. You first call `printline`, then `reboot` which also calls `printline`

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong code.

Comment: `mov al, endofline` should probably be `mov si, endofline`, no?

Comment: Now your code will freeze after the message because of the infinite loop

Comment: Yes, that's what I want (at the moment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mov al, endofline
should be
mov si, endofline

Thanks @Frank Kotler